# Node.jsのnowjsモジュールのインストールについて

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

「Nodeクックブック」の「nowjsを使ってクライアントとサーバーで関数をシェアする」のサンプルプログラムをテストしました。

最初に、以下の通りnowモジュールをインストールしました。

```
  $ npm install now
   ... 中略 ... 
  > Downloading now CLI 7.1.1 [====================] 100%
   ... 中略
  added 1 package in 114.299s
```

次に、プログラムを実行しました。

```
  $ node server
    module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^
   Error: Cannot find module 'now'
```

プログラムの次の箇所でエラーが発生したと思われます。

```
...中略...
var everyone = require('now').initialize(plainHttpServer);
...省略...
```

nowモジュールインストール先ディレクトリの中身は次の通りです。

> ├── download
>   │   ├── dist
>   │   │   ├── download.js
>   │   │   └── now
>   │   └── install.js
>   ├── license.md
>   ├── package.json
>   └── readme.md

ディレクトリに'now.js'というファイルは見当たらず、nowというバイナリがあります。
このnowを起動するとメールアドレスを要求します。zeit社提供のPAASサービスの登録プログラムの様に感じます。

つきましては、nowjsモジュールをインストールする方法に関してご教示をお願いいたします。

尚、当方の動作環境は以下の通りです。

> ホスト : Windows10
>    ゲスト : Ubuntu15.10
>   　VM     : VirtualBox5.1.6

Answer (score 1):

そのライブラリについては知りませんが、たぶん今npmに「now」という名前で登録されてるのはnowjsとは違うものではないでしょうか。その本の情報が古いと思われます。

nowjsをnpmで探しましたが見つかりませんでした。githubには[それらしきもの](https://github.com/Flotype/now)がありました。しかし更新もされておらず使ってる人もあまりいないみたいなので、代わりに[Socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io)を使うことをおすすめします。